# Matlab comapring two webcam live snapshots

Tags: matlab

How do i capture live images from a webcam using matlab and then compare the first and the second image to check for difference  and if there is difference, the second image should be stored. Am using matlab 2012b

Comment: maybe have a look at openCv.. www.opencv.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You have You can use Image Processing Toolbox

http://www.mathworks.nl/help/images/functionlist.html

open two images with 'imread' and calculate difference ('diff'), if sum (diff(img1 - img2)) > 0 than You store second img

Comment: Is there a way of of comapring two images without first storing them on your computer so that instead of imreding them you just capture live ones and compare them then if there  is difference store the second one

Comment: honestly I don't know, I believe that You have to store them anyway, if they are too big or the process will be slow, think about resizing them/converting to for example black/white colors
keep in mind that there are more sophisticated methods in that toolbox like:http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imabsdiff.html as it is implemented in matlab it should be pretty fast